# Access Linux kernel symbols that are not exported via EXPORT_SYMBOL*

Tags: linux, export, kernel, symbols

We have a need to access kernel global vars in net/ipv4/af_inet.c that are not exported explicitly from a loadable kernel module.  We are using 2.6.18 kernel currently.

kallsyms_lookup_name doesn't appear to be available anymore (not exported)

__symbol_get returns NULL (upon further reading, symbol_get/__symbol_get looks through the kernel and existing modules' symbol tables that contains only exported symbol, and it is there to make sure the module from which a symbol is exported is actually loaded)

Is there anyway to access symbols that are not exported from a kernel module?

After doing a lot of reading and looking at answers people provided, it appears that it would be very hard to find one method across many kernel versions since the kAPI changes significantly over time.

Comment: Will `objdump path/to/modulename.ko` do what you need?  You would have to decode the output to determine the corresponding offset in the module, and apply that.  What is the purpose of obtaining a symbol which is not exported?

Comment: yes, we can actuall get the address via /proc/kallsyms in user space and maybe passed in to the module, but that seems a bit hackish so I was wondering whether there is something better.  We are trying to pull part of the networking code out and make it a module so we can do bug fixes without having to reboot the kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method you mentioned before by getting it from /proc/kallsyms or just use the address given in the System.map (which is the same thing), it may seem hackish but this is how I've seen it done before (never really had to do it myself). Either this or you can build your own custom kernel where you actually do EXPORT_SYMBOL on whatever it is you want exported but this is not as portable.

Comment: Jesus, where have you seen the /proc/kallsyms method?  Is that in a production environment?  You are right that we want to work with a standard kernel without having to recompile it.

Comment: @softwareengineer Usually in testing some functionality that we want to add to the kernel without having to recompile it or simply just have it as a removable modular feature. I've seen it maybe once or twice. Before that I saw the System.map one where they just hardcoded the address into the module.

Comment: thanks i will wait a few days and see if anybody else can come up with anything, but if not, i'd happy to accept yours.

Comment: @softwareengineer I would love to see if there's another method as well. Although usually when I want to access non-exported functions I'm working directly in the kernel itself.

Comment: I have accepted jesus' answer because at the end of the day, it did give me some confidence that I am not nuts to think of doing it this way. :)  I will post a follow-up if I find anything better.

Answer (score 5):

If performance is not a big concern, you can traverse the whole list of symbols with `kallsyms_on_each_symbol()` (exported by the kernel for GPL'd modules) and check the names to get the ones you need. I would not recommend doing so unless there is no other choice though.

If you would like to go this way, here is [an example](https://github.com/euspectre/kernel-strider/blob/master/sources/core/module_ms_alloc.c) from one of our projects. See the usage of `kallsyms_on_each_symbol()` as well as the code of `symbol_walk_callback()`, the other parts are irrelevant to this question.

Comment: thanks, Eugene.  however, this function appears to be only available in the more recent kernels.  It wasn't in 2.6.18 or 2.6.25, but it's in 2.6.30. I should have specified 2.6.18 kernel in my original question though.